# dg objects: Z-graded vs. Z/2Z-graded

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, dg-categories

I am wondering: Are there any general theorems or principles relating the theory of Z-graded dg objects and the theory of Z/2Z-graded dg objects? I am mainly interested in dg algebras, dg Lie algebras, and dg categories over fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: When you say "Z/2Z-graded dg objects" you have in mind objects $X$ whose differential is given by maps $X_0\to X_1$ and $X_1\to X_0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Can't you just take even and odd sectors to go from Z-dgas to Z/2Z-dgas?

Comment: Steve: Sure, that's a functor from Z-dgas to Z/2Z-dgas. Then what?

Comment: Isn't quantization the relevant buzzword?

Comment: Z/2-dgas are equivalent to algebras over the commutative Z-dga `$\mathbb{Z}[u^{\pm 1}]$`, where $|u| = 2$.  Based on this you have a number of standard constructions associated to a map of commutative dgas `$R \to S$`, such as tensoring up (equivalent to what Steve Huntsman proposed), forgetting (which gives 2-periodic Z-dgas), and various derived adjunctions which simplify because the range is flat over the domain.  Is this something like what you are interested in?

Comment: One thing coming up for me right now is that the functor from Z-graded things to Z/2-graded things is faithful and essentially surjective but not full.  Whereas some classical constructions I'm trying to understand have natural functors to Z-graded things, and these functors are equivalences of categories.

Comment: @Tyler: Yes! I am interested in that. I must apologize for the vagueness of my question. I have heard about what you're saying before, but when I posted my question I could not remember the details.

Comment: Putting a bounty on this question, hoping that Tyler (or someone else) can elaborate...

Comment: This is discussed, at least for dg-categories, in section 4 of Dyckerhoff's thesis: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0904.4713 where it is needed to understand LG models associated to isolated hypersurface singularities. It elaborates on Tyler's comment.

Comment: Propsition 3.1 in the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0687 by Dyckerhoff and Murfet gives explicit examples of some of the constructions mentioned by Tyler.

Comment: My apologies; I didn't realize that you wanted elaboration.  I don't have a lot of time currently for writing answers, so I might suggest that someone else post if they're watching.  I was mostly trying to suggest that, for example, most of the difference between Z-graded and Z/2-graded is roughly the same as changing from one base field to a slightly larger one.

Comment: A more general question concerning the behavior of (C)DG-categories and (C)DG-modules with respect to a change of the grading group is discussed in Section 2.5 of our new preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0982

Answer (score 2):

To me, the main difference between the Z-graded and Z/2-graded cases is that the former allows certain simplifying boundedness restrictions, which in the latter do not seem to make sense.  Typically, one considers a nonpositive (in the cohomological grading) Z-graded dg-algebra and dg-modules bounded above or below over it, as appropriate.  The case of connected, simply connected (in the sense of cochains, not just cohomology) nonnegative dg-algebra is similar.

The typical simplification achieved under such restrictions is that a dg-module whose underlying graded module is projective is always homotopy projective.  Also, the two ways of defining the differential derived functors (by taking infinite direct sums or products along the diagonals) become equivalent, since the sums/products are actually finite.

When one has to consider dg-algebras that do not satisfy the above kind of restrictions and/or unbounded dg-modules, the Z-graded situation is not any simpler than, and not much different from, the Z/2-graded situation.

References: 1. Keller "Deriving DG-categories"; 2. Husemoller, Moore, Stasheff "Differential homological algebra and homogeneous spaces".